# How to enter inside this part of the JSON?

Tags: fs

The JSON file:

```
"skins": [
  {
    "id": 266000,
    "name": "default",
    "num": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 266001,
    "name": "Justicar Aatrox",
    "num": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 266002,
    "name": "Mecha Aatrox",
    "num": 2
  }
]
```

I want to pick all the `skins` numbers, but I don't know how to enter in the `num` field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a JSON file named `skins.json`
and it contains the following code

```
{
  skins: [
    { id: 266000, name: 'default', num: 0 },
    { id: 266001, name: 'Justicar Aatrox', num: 1 },
    { id: 266002, name: 'Mecha Aatrox', num: 2 }
  ]
}
```

In nodejs you can do something like this

```
const skins_json = require("./skins.json")

console.log(skins_json.skins.map(x=>x.num));
```

If you have a simple plain object

```js
    const skins =  [
        { id: 266000, name: 'default', num: 0 },
        { id: 266001, name: 'Justicar Aatrox', num: 1 },
        { id: 266002, name: 'Mecha Aatrox', num: 2 }
      ];

     console.log(skins.map(x=>x.num));
```